# Adding Media Manager in Menu Item List

Tags: component, media-manager

How can I add Media Manager in Menu Item Type list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a work around to my problem, first I copied the administration files in site folder and create a default.xml file to my desire view on my case **medialist** view is what I need to show in Menu Item Type and create a **STRING DEFINITION** in administration language file but this still will not show in MENU ITEM TYPE LIST you need to update your media.xml and under the **administration tag** add a tag for menu something like tihs **Media Manager** and update the version of your media component save and zip it. done!

Answer (score 0):

**Creation of Media manager:**
Goto backend -> Content -> Media manager -> Create new folder and upload the need files.
**Creation of article:** 
Goto Article manager -> Give title name -> click the image button and upload the media manager files -> click save.
**Creation of Menu item type:**
Goto Menu -> Main menu -> New -> Menu title -> Select the menu item type of media manager article.
Then you can see the output in frontend.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the answer I'm looking for I managed to find a work around to my problem, first I copied the administration files in site folder and create a default.xml file to my desire view on my case **medialist** view is what I need to show in Menu Item Type and create a **STRING DEFINITION** in administration language file but this still will not show in MENU ITEM TYPE LIST you need to update your media.xml and under the **administration tag** add a tag for menu something like tihs **<menu>Media Manager</menu>** add change the version of your media component save and zip it. done!